# How to run a javascript site in Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, iis, pug

I've been given some code for a website that I need to modify.  I primarily work with asp.net sites and .net winforms in Visual Studio.  I can't figure out how to run this site in VS.  When I use CTRL-F5 I get a "403.14 - Forbidden" message.  I'm guessing that I need to specifically reference some file in the URL or set a default file, but I don't see any html file to reference and referencing any of the js files just brings up the text of the file.  Can someone explain how to get this code running in VS?

Here's what I see in VS:
[image]

Here's what I see when pressing CTRL-F5:

[image]

Comment: what is the content of the `routes/index.js` file and the `package.json` file?

Comment: You'd better use VSCode and the related npm/yarn commands (unless this JS project uses .esproj of VS2022).

Comment: Did this link solve your problem? [HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden when you open an IIS webpage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/http-403-14-forbidden-webpage).